# Convert an SVG element to a g element using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, viewbox

I am using D3 in a page where my objective is to superimpose two groups of paths : I have the earth coastlines as a background map (imported from a GeoJSON file), and I want to superimpose an old map on it, which is a separate SVG : http://bl.ocks.org/bperel/9943623/250fc9af2e09bf176f6d510e0b59fe643d792287

The SVG loading went well, however I would like my two maps to be included inside the same SVG element : it will be easier if I want the maps to be panned or zoomed. The issue here is that the external SVG has a specific viewbox, so if I move its <g> elements to the other SVG, the coordinates get messy. Hence my question : is there a way to convert the 2nd SVG to a <g> element that I could include in the first SVG ? Maybe d3 knows how to do that but I couldn't find such a tool in the documentation.

Comment: In general, I would suggest just adding the external SVG as a nested SVG and setting it's x, y, height and width as appropriate.  However, for your maps I'm not sure how you're planning to get the map projections to line up just right.

Comment: I'll worry about the projections later, I suppose here that they are the same for the two maps.

Comment: In principle, all you have to do is take the top-level element of the nested SVG, detach it from the DOM and reattach it underneath a `g` element in the other SVG.

Comment: No, you can't, that's my point : the 2nd SVG has a viewBox parameter, meaning that everything inside of it is relative to these coordinates,  therefore if you move one of the <path> elements included for the 2nd SVG to the first one, this path will probably be out of range, because the first SVG doesn't have a viewBox

Comment: What about <foreignobject>?
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to zoom/pan the superimposed SVG's, Include **both** svg's in a `<g>` container element and attach zoom behavior to the `<g>` container.

Essentually, you will have:

```
<svg id=topSVG>
<g id=container>
<svg id=projection1>
....
</svg>
<svg id=projection2>
....
</svg>
</g>
</svg>
```

Below is a snippet relating to my mouswheel zoom for d3:

```
var myZoom=d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([.1, 1000]).on("zoom", mouseWheelZoom)

function callZoomBehavior()
{
    //---attach to root svg---
    d3.select("#"+SVGId)
    .call(myZoom)
    //---reset from previous file call---
    myZoom.translate([0,0])
    myZoom.scale(1)
    PrevScale=1
}

var PrevScale //--previous scale event---
function mouseWheelZoom()
{
    //--place in d3 object--
    var zoomG=d3.select("#topZoomG")
    if(PrevScale!=d3.event.scale) //--transition on scale change--
    {
        zoomG.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
    }
    else //--no transition on pan---
    {
        zoomG.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
    }
    PrevScale=d3.event.scale
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to be a good idea, however the pan/zoom handling that I attached to the new <g> element doesn't seem to work so well : besides not being really fluid (maybe because the embedded SVG is quite big ?), the movement sometimes follows a wrong direction and I get JavaScript errors : http://bl.ocks.org/bperel/9943623/7d2e878a9504e0b4e15a749104e0c3674e2c3908 .

Comment: If you are using d3 mousewheel zoom; I also have experienced very poor response in FF. IE seems the most responsive. The size of my SVG file was 470KB. I would guess if your file is over 500KB you will continue to have this problem. One solution would be abandon the mousewheel zoom/pan and instead provide a user event to zoom into an area.

Comment: It is indeed more fluid on IE, however I still notice that from time to time the map goes to the wrong direction as I'm dragging it. It occurs more often when I try to drag the map quickly it seems. Did I implement the drag callback function incorrectly ?

Comment: I'll add(above) a snippet if my mousewheel for d3, maybe you can see the problem..give me a few moments.

Comment: I accept your answer even though i still have these drag fluidity issues : the idea of embedding the SVG in a <g> element helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`originalSVG` = the SVG element you want to clone and convert into g element
`quasiClone` = the result of that
`parentOfClone` = parent below you want to put your new g element

```
    var quasiClone = parentOfClone.append("g");
    for (var i=0; i<originalSVG.childNodes.length; i++){
        var child = originalSVG.childNodes[i];
        var childClone = child.cloneNode(true);
        quasiClone.node().appendChild(childClone);
    }
```